# Pass Iterable<CSVRecord> to method

Tags: java, csv

I am having trouble passing a Iterable to a method.  Right now I have a method that does the below:

```
public Iterable<CSVRecord> parseCSVFileContents(BufferedReader inFile) throws IOException
{
    Reader inCSV = new BufferedReader(inFile);
    Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse(inCSV);

    return records;
}
```

The problem is I have to run this for each test condition I am trying to find a match for. I would rather call it once, store it, and then get it inside the for loop.  But when I try that I get empty results returned.  It works fine and I can spin through the CSV if I call the `Iterable` directly in the method I’m supposed to pass it to.

Any thoughts what I am doing wrong, or is this not possible with `Iterable`?

Comment: In general, you should be able to pass objects that implement `Iterable` to for loops. It might be helpful to see the innards of the `parse` function, just to see what specific object you are using to create the iterable records.